# wordpress throws 404 when using sound clouds wp link

Tags: wordpress

Having trouble getting the following to work in wordpress:

From the share button at https://soundcloud.com/stream
I get the following code:
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13081354" params="" width=" 100%" height="166" iframe="true" /]

Then after installing the latest sound cloud is gold plugin for wordpress...
Using sound cloud is gold i presume is the correct way to play the link from soundcloud website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OLD code:
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13081354" params="" width=" 100%" height="166" iframe="true" /]

NEW code:
[soundcloud id="13081354"]